# URL Word-wrap Issue

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

Word-wrap issues seem to have been asked and answered loads of times but I can't find exactly what I want.

Basically, I'm using

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

to break a URL written into a DIV so it doesn't overflow. Works fine except visually it's very poor with certain URLs. For example,

```
www.stackoverflow.com/questions/anotherbit/andabitmore
```

it'll work fine and wrap at the end of a line. However, with,

```
www.stackoverflow.com?fishingandthesomemore=someothertext
```

it will break at the ? rather than the end of the line.

Anyone got any clever ideas ?

Comment: The browser probably just doesn't consider the "=" to be a word separator, meaning you have one really long word that it can't break up in nice ways. Try other wrap modes.

Comment: Erm. Not exactly. The ? is forcing a line break.

Comment: Have you tried url encoding it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a php doc you can use the php wordwrap native function like so...

```
<div>
<a href="google.com"><?php echo wordwrap('www.stackoverflow.com?fishingandthesomemore=someothertext', 30, "<br />", true); ?></a>
</div>
```